# Templating language for both client-side and server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, templates, client-side, server-side

I'm investigating JavaScript templates as a way to render our views. The goal is to be able to render client-side for users that have JavaScript enabled to to render the same templates/data server side for those users (and crawlers) that don't.

**Requirements**

1. Client side rendering.
2. Server side rendering (JVM support a nice-to-have).
3. Reasonable support for loops, conditionals, text manipulation, partials, macros and extensions/plugins.
4. Reasonably big/active community of users.

**Unsatisfactory solutions found so far**

1. [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/): supports server and client side rendering, big/active community, but the "logic-less" templates seem very restrictive and painful.
2. [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) plus [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/): JS templates like underscore provide all the template flexibility I need, but rendering them server-side using Node.js is VERY fragile. node.js is new and fairly unstable and its package management (exports...) requires lots of hacks for things to work properly.
3. [Google Closure Templates](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/): these compile down to JS and Java and have a lot of the features I want. Unfortunately, browsing the Google groups, it looks like lots of basic features are missing (such as ability to [loop over associative arrays](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-templates-discuss/browse_thread/thread/a65179c527580aab/cfb883bb88e84df9)) and the [documentation for making your own plugins](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/plugins.html) is very sparse and painful looking. Moreover, I can't tell who in the online community is using it, Google isn't accepting open source contributions for it, and they don't have the bandwidth to release new features.
4. [isotope](https://github.com/elado/isotope): write templates in JS and use [Johnson](https://github.com/jbarnette/johnson/), a Ruby wrapper for the Mozilla SpiderMonkey JS runtime, to render those templates server side. Seems promising, but the project hasn't had commits in over 6 months.
5. [Liquid](https://github.com/tobi/liquid) with [Liquid.js](https://github.com/darthapo/liquid.js): the Liquid templating language looks superb, but the liquid.js project seems to be untested (no testing in IE!), has no documentation, it's not clear if anyone uses it, and it hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: This is an interesting topic. Since you require the template language support both server and client side, I am a bit curious how a server side template engine correctly process the template on server side dynamic content and leave the client side content (including template instructions) untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up picking [dust.js](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/). Check out [Leaving JSPs in the dust](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates) and [The client-side templating throwdown](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Use [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/). It's pretty much got all the features you ask.

It can be used with express.js out of the box and it works nicely on the client.

As a bonus I would use backbone.js to do MVC on the client & server.

Of course this does rely on node.js. I feel that using express, now & backbone allows you a lot of stable control with node.js. Not to mention that SSJS is simply awesome and that code re-use is fantastic.

Comment: EJS does look like a pretty good templating language. My one worry is the stability/maturity of node and the fact that you need to get the ejs helpers separately (https://github.com/masahiroh/express-helpers).

Comment: @YevgeniyBrikman didn't realise I had to get those seperately. I like writing a lot of real HTML.

Comment: ...and the express-helpers don't work properly. Trying to follow their instructions and set `app = helpers.all(app);` causes Node.js to throw an exception with an instanceof check. Gah, this node.js stuff may be too immature for this project.

Comment: @YevgenlyBrikman don't use the helpers. Problem solved. The issue with node is lots of earlier plugins don't upgrade to match the 0.4 compliance.

Answer (score -1):

I would opt for XSLT (http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp)

Comment: I can't find anything about this topic on w3fools... can you be more specific?

Comment: Well I didn't vote down your answer, nor never used XSLT, just wanted to make things justified after a reference to w3schools

Comment: XSLT is cumbersome, memory hungry, unwieldy technology. Probably the only one known from XML books that allows declarative tree transformations. People like the concept, but the real work with it is horrible.